# Do deformations of a vector bundle form a vector space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves, deformation-theory, obstruction-theory

I wonder whether deformations of a vector bundle $F$ over a local Artinian ring $(A, m)$ form a vector space $\operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes m$, or what happens in a sequence  (*) below? I read two different discussions, one in Huybrechts, Lehn *Geometry of moduli space of sheaves*, another in Hartshorne *Lectures on deformation theory*, but it still looks bizarre.

**Definitions.** Let $F$ be a vector bundle on a nice variety $X$ over a field $k$. Let $A$ be a local Artinian ring over $k$, for example $A=k[t]/(t^n)$, and recall that a deformation of $F$ on $A$ is a vector bundle $F'$ on $X \times \operatorname{Spec} A$ with a fixed isomorphism $F'|_X \to F$. Denote by $D_F(A)$ the set of all deformations of $F$ over $A$, so that $D_F$ is a covariant functor from local Artinian rings to sets. A small extension is a sequence
$$0 \to K \to A' \to A \to 0$$
such that the maximal ideal $m'$ of $A'$ goes to the maximal ideal $m$ of $A$, and such that $Km'=0$ holds. A typical example is
$$0 \to k \xrightarrow{t^n} k[t]/(t^{n+1}) \to k[t]/(t^n) \to 0.$$

**Theorem.** Every small extension gives a sequence
$$\operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes K \to D_F(A') \to D_F(A) \to \operatorname{Ext}^2(F, F) \otimes K,\qquad(*)$$
which is exact in a sense of sets with a chosen element, and also functorial.

But $D_F(k)=0$, so $D_F(A)=\operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes m$ holds at least for $A=k[t]/(t^2)$. So does this equality holds for a general $A$? And why a sequence
$$\operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes K \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes m' \to \operatorname{Ext}^1(F, F) \otimes m \to \operatorname{Ext}^2(F, F) \otimes K$$
is so similar to a long exact sequence for $\operatorname{Hom}$-functor? At last, what is a correct way to think about the sequence (*): Huybrechts, Lehn choose an injective resolution, while Hartshorne uses Čech cocycles, but both look like just ways to calculate a cohomology by hand.

Comment: Aren't the deformations a torsor? So, they shouldn't even naturally be a group. Specifically, you say that $D_F(A)$ is a pointed set--what is the distinguished element?

Comment: @AlexYoucis, a trivial deformation $F'=F \otimes A$ (here, deformations are on $X \times \operatorname{Spec} A$, not some general $X' \supset X$).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I misread! Another silly question--is it even true that $D_F(A)$ is a group if the rank of $F$ is greater than $1$? Even passing to isomorphism classes this seems unlikely. Sorry if I'm missing something silly!

Comment: @AlexYoucis, a tensor product of deformations over $F$ is a deformation over $F \otimes F$, not $F$. About whether it is a group/vector space I do not understand, probably not)

Comment: Right, precisely--the only case where this seems doable is if $F$ is the trivial bundle. Anyways, good luck with your question!

Comment: @AlexYoucis, unfortunately, then $\operatorname{Ext}^{>0}(\mathcal O_X, \mathcal O_X)=0$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deformations over a general Artinian ring won't be a vector space: they are points of a moduli space (the moduli of vector bundles), which is (typically, and certainly in this case) non-linear.

The deformations over $k[t]/(t^2)$ *do* form a vector space: this is a general property, namely that the Zariski tangent space at a point of a scheme is a vector space.    In the case of deformations of a vector bundle, it admits the description as an $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ that you recall.